# How to plot a heat map by giving scaling the color for row-wise?

Tags: r, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have a selected data table for DEG and interested in plotting a heatmap by using a color gradient row-wise (without scaling or normalizing the data).

Giving a color key for the whole data set is not practical since there is a big variation in values and I do not see any difference row-wise?

Could I have any tips?

```
col <- colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"))
    heatmap.2(
        as.matrix(df),
        Rowv = F,
        Colv = F,
        col = col,
        margins = c(7, 10),
        trace = "none",
        density.info = "none",
        colsep = 0:ncol(df),
        sepcolor = "black",
        sepwidth = c(0.001,1),
        xlab = "Identifier",
        ylab = "Genes",
        dendrogram = "none"
    )
```

sample data

```
    structure(list(Gene = c("GeneID1G05870", "GeneID1G06650", "GeneID1G10600", 
"GeneID1G22770", "GeneID1G70760", "GeneID1G75780", "GeneID1G78440", 
"GeneID4G04620", "GeneID5G44440", "GeneID5G45690", "GeneID5G46900"
), WT_5g = c(70.54931232, 15.2694023, 1.892956422, 545.6485918, 
15.97369842, 318.9142651, 12.33090087, 17.06953467, 727.3605786, 
4.006229211, 65.03893698), mut2_5g = c(163.7483609, 47.50279792, 
13.45503913, 773.5268439, 11.54887723, 316.9838118, 24.85384623, 
48.51313392, 786.8184899, 38.71347161, 134.5457693), mut5_5g = c(253.6250256, 
106.3434108, 34.94408181, 1095.389403, 57.1999803, 794.9872288, 
39.96439114, 99.75490643, 1514.192806, 57.84901542, 237.6958904
), mut9_5g = c(287.1381463, 66.9971383, 21.59875084, 954.1244021, 
20.83025268, 801.7238687, 66.0781162, 63.57763566, 1246.870329, 
237.3403603, 190.9073112), WT_10g = c(15.29399518, 7.941852264, 
0, 71.43453561, 18.17320504, 34.43781165, 0.348538367, 4.315727758, 
84.47740876, 10.04915004, 11.66588421), mut2_10g = c(84.2469726, 
113.1437239, 30.09371087, 405.6859217, 128.5341721, 189.4707842, 
1.426441184, 84.78886255, 292.4110234, 26.37416694, 55.5562682
), mut5_10g = c(65.28018809, 73.48406109, 18.71876463, 216.9721116, 
86.58965327, 146.1711049, 1.922723661, 49.022981, 215.7004656, 
13.64504346, 30.91836455), mut9_10g = c(209.5799583, 184.402664, 
64.06641698, 789.8347533, 219.402683, 598.4247051, 4.237600312, 
134.3549729, 919.7119639, 83.31465527, 132.8361343), WT_25g = c(21.17571441, 
18.32847966, 3.579804864, 113.631977, 27.12339777, 54.49523867, 
0, 8.381341869, 105.2166627, 4.296827283, 7.778837366), mut2_25g = c(33.61722838, 
56.56505593, 17.67585763, 155.1388213, 51.06149893, 75.26381144, 
0, 43.96873694, 62.91770026, 12.34127182, 15.12855071), mut5_25g = c(98.01331714, 
195.8268408, 31.54189434, 430.8813341, 229.0556693, 254.222979, 
2.131526079, 79.89003245, 224.6937695, 13.29087517, 35.26540136
), mut9_25g = c(117.4316631, 125.7919799, 29.01108699, 316.3714893, 
130.0397543, 309.1774138, 4.151423846, 55.6655899, 415.511104, 
33.94733367, 50.72723825)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: So, you're only wanting to cluster rows but not columns?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps even clustering is not very essential. I only need a heat map to visualise each row sample change.

Comment: Okay. I still don't think I'm clear on what you're looking for. I'll post what I have and you can correct anywhere I may be missing something.

Comment: Hi Todd, thank you. In your answer for whole heatmap there is a one colour key, because of this we are unable to see rows with small values and it’s dynamics. What I am interested in is for each raw I wanna use same colour gradient (high, medium,low) without giving a colour key with values. By giving a colour key we have take  all the rows in to account.sorry if I mislead you

Comment: I have edited it to only scale rows, which should allow row dynamics to appear. Is this more in line with what you're seeking?

Comment: Thank you Todd this is what I am looking for. Have you scaled the data

Comment: I did, but only within rows. A similar thing could be done by heat mapping each row by their own specific quantiles, but I didn't see any clear way to do this using `heatmap.2`. It is possible by using for loops and stacked 1-dim heat maps, but that would get awfully messy.

Comment: Thanks a heap Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have saved your sample data (with gene names) as `df`. The code to follow produces a heat map.

```
library(gplots)
dat = as.matrix(df[,-1])
h.map <- heatmap.2(dat, Rowv = F,
                  Colv = F,
                  margins = c(7, 10),
                  trace = "none",
                  density.info = "none",
                  colsep = 0:ncol(df),
                  sepcolor = "black",
                  sepwidth = c(0.001,1),
                  xlab = "Identifier",
                  ylab = "Genes",
                  dendrogram = "none",
                  scale = 'row') #scaled rows to allow small values to show
```

Output:

[image]